# Keep while displaying into browser the layout got from XML file through XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, layout

I am writing a XSL file which parses XML into HTML for the IE browser. I 'd like to know how to keep in the browser the XML data layout while showing that to users.

For example, being that XML file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='myXSL.xsl'?>
<LISTS>
  <SCR>repository</SCR>
  <Dependency><ArtifactId>maven</ArtifactId>
  <GroupId>NO</GroupId>
<!--Display a little later into browser the detail node value as in below-->
 <detail1>
 Here is a text detail 1:
 project
 ...
 repositories
   repository
     id my-internal-site id
     url http://myserver/repo url
   repository
 repositories
 ...
 project
 </detail1>
 <detail2> Here is a text detail 2:
 </detail2>
 </Dependency>
 ...
</LISTS>
```

The snippet below from my xsl shows the current node detail1/detail2 values. But I need to have that output as written in my XML file

```
<table width="100%" id="tb">                         
 <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="detail1"/>
     </td><td><xsl:value-of select="detail2"/></td></tr> 
</table>
```

This is the actual result get with my xsl:
[image]

Nevertheless, I need to have into the table element this output:

```
Here is a text detail:
 project
 ...
 repositories
   repository
     id my-internal-site id
     url http://myserver/repo url
   repository
 repositories
 ...
 project
```

Thank you, in advance for your valuable assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the issue is that HTML will usually treat all whitespace as single spaces. How about using a `<pre>` element?

```
<table width="100%" id="tb">                         
 <tr>
   <td><pre><xsl:value-of select="detail1"/></pre></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="detail2"/></td>
 </tr> 
</table>
```

The other option is to use an iterative template to convert the spaces and newlines into `&#xA0;`s and `<br/>`s, but this is much simpler and probably just as good.

Comment: I'm surprised - positively! Thank you very much